# angularJS: Why does binding to scope inside a directive result in lost content of ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have this fairly simple HTML structure:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div dir1="xy"><div>dir1static</div><div ng-repeat="item in items">dir1</div></div>
    <div dir2="xy"><div>dir2static</div><div ng-repeat="item in items">dir2</div></div>
</div>
```

And two directives of which one (dir2) has an attribute bound to the scope:

```
myApp.directive("dir1", function () {

    return {
        restrict: "A",    
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        }
    };
});

myApp.directive("dir2", function () {

    return {
        restrict: "A", 
        scope: {
            dir2: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes) {
        }
    };
});
```

Using the following Controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.xy = 2;
    $scope.items = [1,2,3];
}
```

results in this output:

```
dir1static
dir1
dir1
dir1
dir2static
```

So essentially, the ng-repeat part is not rendered when using the second directive. Is there any logical explanation for this?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/LBwAJ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your second directive is creating an isolated scope.

```
scope: {
    dir2: "="
},
```

So, the collection you are iterating, `items`, does not get inherited into the second directive scope.

From [documentation here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes):

> In AngularJS, a child scope normally prototypically inherits from its
>   parent scope. One exception to this rule is a directive that uses
>   scope: { ... } -- this creates an "isolate" scope that does not
>   prototypically inherit. This construct is often used when creating a
>   "reusable component" directive.

A simple way to make it work would be to pass in a reference to the `items` list in the second directive scope:

```
scope: {
    dir2: "=",
    items: "=",
},
```

And then pass in `items` as an attribute to wire up the existing `ng-repeat`:

```
<div dir2="xy" items="items">
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zkuXq/).

Comment: Thanks, I see, that's really good to know! But is there a way to make it work?

Comment: depends on what you are trying to do. :)  I'm not sure I understand your objective fully from your question.

Comment: See my edit, I've provided a working fiddle with a simple solution.

Comment: Cool, thanks a lot :) It's just something I sumbled upon by accident, by trying to solve another problem. So it was more like an out-of-curiosity question.